# how to auto play, full screen and no controls on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, video, mobile, autoplay

is there a way to get a full screen video to auto play, with no controls, to work on mobile devices?

The methods I have used have just displayed a play button with a black background.

```
<video poster="#url#" id="backgroundvideo">
<source src="#url#" type="video/mp4">
<source src="#url#" type="video/ogg">
<source src="#url#" type="video/webm">
</video>

backgroundvideo { 
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -1000;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url(#url#) no-repeat;
background-size: cover; 
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Please share what *methods* you have tried

Comment: i have tried adding many different file formats and have I been messing around with disabling posters, autoplay, fullscreen, ect

Comment: We would appreciate to see your code, ideally a jsFiddle demo

Comment: edited post to contain code.

Comment: @Bycrome see my answer should work for you

Comment: @SaucedApples thanks for your help mate its working just got to work out how to get rid of controls and make it auto play.

Comment: @Bycrome  I have edited my answer.  It will remove controls.  Make sure you have the right type set (ie `video/mp4`) and you can set a display size.

Comment: @Bycrome did that work?

Comment: You won't get autoplay to work on *mobile devices* as they do not prefetch the data (in order to save the visitor's dataplan). That therefore means you won't be able to hide the controls...

Answer (score 0):

The bellow will autoplay the source:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="changeme.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you wanted to display a message  if the user's browser does not support the method:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="changeme.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video.
</video>
```

The above code is supported by the following browsers and their minimum version numbers:

[image]